# RabbitMQ behavioural difference between Consumer Ack vs Consumer Nack with requeue false?

Tags: rabbitmq

In RabbitMQ, after consumer receives and processes message, I can either `ack` it, or I can `nack` it.

Nacking the message with requeue true puts in back into the queue, however, requeue false does not.

So I was wondering what's the difference between Consumer Ack vs Consumer Nack with requeue false, or can we just `ack` instead of the `nack`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> between Consumer Ack vs Consumer Nack with requeue false

See https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html

```
Dead Letter Exchanges
Messages from a queue can be "dead-lettered"; 
that is, republished to an exchange when any of the following events occur:

The message is negatively acknowledged by a consumer using basic.reject or basic.nack 
with requeue parameter set to false.
```

....

In short: `basic.nack` with `requeue = false` redirects the messages to the DLX exchange (if dlx is configured).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't using DLX in my setup yet so didn't see any differences in the broker, or thought about checking it.